# jQuery datepicker not working in paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this small issue where I can't figure out why this datepicker doesn't work:

The HTML part is:

```
Test <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/>
<p>Startdatum:<input type="text" id="startTime"></p>  
<p>Enddatum:<input type="text" id="endTime"/></p>
```

The JavaScript part is:

```
$('#startTime').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});

$('#endTime').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});

$('#date1').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy"
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h10t7ed6/

Can someone tell me why the datepicker doesn't appear?

Comment: If you check the browser devtools on your JSFiddle, and view the console, you will see the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`.  Which tells you you have not included JQueryUI (which is where the Datepicker comes from).  You need to be using devtools when you are developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need JQuery UI support as well:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also,

```
<script>
         $(function() {
          $('#startTime').datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
         });

        $('#endTime').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
         });

        $('#date1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "m/d/yy"
      });

   });
</script>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle doesn't need to be wrapped in `$(function() { ... }` and whether OP's code needs that depends on how the code is "associated" ("included"?) with the page, which we can't tell from the OP question.